# Add local storage to save canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas, local-storage

I do not know how to add local storage to save the drawing made on the canvas so when the page is reloaded the existing drawing is loaded onto the canvas through local storafe. I do not have must experience so would appreciate if someone could edit my code with the local storage addition. Many thanks in advance!

Here is my JS:

```
var canvas, ctx,
    brush = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        color: '#000000',
        size: 10,
        down: false,
    },
    strokes = [],
    currentStroke = null;

function redraw () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    for (var i = 0; i < strokes.length; i++) {
        var s =strokes[i];
        ctx.strokeStyle = s.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = s.size;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x, s.points[0].y);
        for (var j = 0; j < s.points.length; j++){
            var p = s.points[j];
            ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}
function init () {
    canvas = $('#draw');
    canvas.attr({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
    });
    ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');


    function mouseEvent (e){
                brush.x = e.pageX;
        brush.y = e.pageY;

        currentStroke.points.push({
            x: brush.x,
            y: brush.y,

        });



        redraw();
    }
    canvas.mousedown(function (e){
        brush.down = true;

        currentStroke = {
            color: brush.color,
            size: brush.size,
            points: [],
        };
        strokes.push(currentStroke);

        mouseEvent(e);
    }) .mouseup(function (e) {
        brush.down = false;

        mouseEvent(e);

        currentStroke = null;
    }) .mousemove(function (e) {
        if (brush.down)
            mouseEvent(e);
    });

    $('#save-btn').click(function () {
        window.open(canvas[0].toDataURL());
    });
    $('#undo-btn').click(function (){
        strokes.pop();
        redraw();
    });
    $('#clear-btn').click(function (){
        strokes = [];
        redraw();
    });

    $('#color-picker').on('input', function () {
        brush.color = this.value;
    });
    $('#brush-size').on('input', function () {
        brush.size = this.value;
    });
    }
$(init);
```

Comment: What are you stuck on? Localstorage stores strings so serialize/unserialize the canvas content.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to actually implement the local storage

Comment: You don't need to implement localstorage, you use the API. Something like `localStorage.setItem('image', canvas.toDataURL());`

Comment: How would I make this work in my code? (I have barely any coding knowledge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Canvas.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#canvasjs) helper you can simply do:

```
const canvas = new Canvas( 'my-canvas' );
canvas.saveToStorage( 'balls' );
```

where

- `my-canvas` is the **canvas id**
- `balls` is the **key** to save it as

To later restore a canvas state:

```
const canvas = new Canvas( 'my-canvas' );
canvas.restoreFromStorage( 'balls' );
```

Load [Canvas.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#canvasjs):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/Canvas.js">
```

**EDIT**

After reading the below post (Thank you @Shashank), ive made a jsfiddle with the complete code to achieve continous drawing. It automatically saves the last stroke on mouseup and loads it in on refresh. Check it out!

It uses [Canvas.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#canvasjs) and [Pointer.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#pointerjs):

https://jsfiddle.net/wk5ttqa2/

**EDIT 2**

Just for fun... this is as simple as it can get really:

https://jsfiddle.net/GustavGenberg/1929f15t/1/

Note that it does not draw complete lines when moving fast (depends on framerate)...

Comment: Maybe you would wanna have _two_ **separate** functions in Canvas.js namely `saveCanvasToStorage` - which will save it as an image - as it does now (I looked up the library function) and `saveCanvasElementsToStorage` - which will save an `array` to the localStorage. Let me know if you think I can fork and add a commit to your repo.

Comment: What elements are we talking about here? The stroke "elements"?

Comment: Did you check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082509/add-local-storage-to-save-canvas-drawing/48083860#answer-48085123)? In this case, the elements are being stored in an array named `strokes`. Try out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/u0316q1k/2/) link.

Comment: Ok, what and how should you be able store? Im wondering if it will be a good solution if you can load and save the handyObject to storage? Feel free to fork n commit :)

Comment: Did you try drawing any images and clicking the button "Save to localStorage" at the bottom? Saving as a string as JSON parsing it to fetch?

Comment: Yes and that is a good solution indeed.  Thats the way to go if you want to be able to clear the canvas and continue painting without loosing old strokes. Regarding the changes to Canvas.js, the only option I see is to be able to save the [handyObject](https://github.com/GustavGenberg/handy-front-end#handyobject) to storage and then retrieve it. That will cover up most usecases.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas.js will save the canvas as an image to the localStorage which is not helpful in your case as you're storing the mouse events in an array.

**If you're looking for a solution which lets continue the drawing on canvas along with restoring old (saved) elements, what you would need is storing of the canvas elements (`strokes` array in your case) in the localStorage and restoring, redrawing the canvas**.

Here's a demo doing that:

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/u0316q1k/2/)

1. Draw anything on the canvas.
2. Click on the "Save to local storage" button at the bottom.
3. Refresh the page.

> To clear localStorage, clear the browser cache.

**Relevant code changes:**

1. Added a button in HTML to save to local storage

   ```
   <button id="save-to-local-storage">
      Save to local storage
   </button>
   ```
2. Saving the `strokes` array to the localStorage on above button click.

   ```
   $('#save-to-local-storage').click(function () {
     localStorage.setItem('canvas_strokes', JSON.stringify(strokes)); 
   });
   ```
3. On **page refresh**, check if localStorage has items set and if YES, redraw the canvas:

   ```
   // check if localstorage has an array of strokes saved 
   if(localStorage.getItem('canvas_strokes')) { 
      strokes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('canvas_strokes'));
      redraw();
   }
   ```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: A new function is implemented to Canvas.js and I made a fiddle with the complete code. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Glad I could contribute! :)